# Deserializing Java object with type parameters

Tags: java, generics, serialization

I had the idea to wrap Java's `SealedObject`, which deals with encrypting data that is serialized, by adding a type parameter (type parameters were introduced to the language later than `SealedObject`). It looks fairly straightforward:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;

public class SealedObject<T extends Serializable> {

    private final javax.crypto.SealedObject obj;

    public SealedObject(T obj, Cipher c) throws IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        this.obj = new javax.crypto.SealedObject(obj, c);
    }

    public final String getAlgorithm() {
        return obj.getAlgorithm();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final T getObject(Key key) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        return (T) obj.getObject(key);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final T getObject(Cipher c) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        return (T) obj.getObject(c);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final T getObject(Key key, String provider)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException {
        return (T) obj.getObject(key, provider);
    }

}
```

After I implemented this, I started wondering whether it will really work properly. The `getObject` methods declare a `ClassNotFoundException` which makes sense to me, since the deserializing system might not have loaded a class for the serialized type.

In my case with using type parameters, how does the deserializing system deal with the case where it doesn't know the class for the `T` that was originally serialized? Is there anything extra that I need to do to handle that case?

On the other hand, I suspect that it might just "work", which meaning that everything will compile okay, and I'll just get the usual `ClassNotFoundException` when I call `getObject`.

I'm not really sure how to test that case -- something to do with `ClassLoader`s? Would appreciate any views on whether this will work, why or why not, and how to write the test.

Comment: "How does the deserializing system deal with the case where it doesn't know the class for the T that was originally serialized?": by throwing `ClassNotFoundException`. Test it by serializing the `SealedObject` to a file, deleting the .class file, then trying to deserialize and unseal from the file.

Comment: The `T` type parameter is entirely irrelevant. This class works exactly the same way it worked before adding the type parameter. When there’s code using a `SealedObject<Foo>` and class `Foo` is absent, there are likely more dependencies in *that* code which might make it fail even before getting to try a deserialization. E.g., how do you even construct an instance of `SealedObject<Foo>` without the class `Foo`?